# Querying the database in a Django unit test

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I am creating a web application which has a `POST` endpoint, that does two things:

1. Saves the `POST`ed data (a university review) in the database.
2. Redirects the user to an overview page.

Here is the code for it:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    review = Review(university=university,
                    user=User.objects.get(pk=1),
                    summary=request.POST['summary'])

    review.save()

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('university_overview', args=(university_id,)))
```

I haven't yet implemented passing the user data to the endpoint, and that's why I'm saving everything under the user with `pk=1`.

My test is as follows:

```
class UniversityAddReviewTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        user = User.objects.create(username="username", password="password", email="email")
        university = University.objects.create(name="Oxford University", country="UK", info="Meh", rating="9")
        Review.objects.create(university=university, summary="Very nice", user_id=user.id)
        Review.objects.create(university=university, summary="Very bad", user_id=user.id)

        new_review = {
            'summary': 'It was okay.'
        }

        self.response = Client().post('/%s/reviews/add' % university.id, new_review)

    def test_database_updated(self):
        self.assertEqual(len(Review.objects.all()), 3)
```

The result is this:

```
  File ".../core/views.py", line 20, in detail
    user=User.objects.get(pk=1),
  File ".../ENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File ".../ENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 403, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
django.contrib.auth.models.DoesNotExist: User matching query does not exist.
```

Why is this happening? I know the user I'm creating has a `pk=1`, as when I actually print it during the test it's 1.

Comment: is this the only place in your tests where you create a user?

Comment: no, I have other tests that create users as well

Comment: it is however the only user in the specific `TestCase` class

Comment: oh and are there are test methods in this `TestCase` besides `test_database_updated`?

Comment: there is a `test_html` method that only does `self.assertRedirects(self.response, "/4/overview/")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pk` is defined by the database. Something could make it not equal to 1 in your test.

Try this in your setUp method

```
user = User.objects.create_user(
    username="username",
    password="password",
    email="test@example.com",
    id=1
)
assert user.pk == 1
```

Comment: That worked, thank you! Is there a convention around using `create_user` instead of just `create`?

Comment: `create_user` is a method available to the User manager. It hashes the password and a few other actions.  Creating a user with just `create` would result in a user that cannot log in via standard login forms because the password saved in the database in not hashed. That was not the fix though. The fix was specifying id=1

Comment: Yes, I realised, it was a curiosity question :D Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Take advantage of using `self` and then you can try this instead:

```
class UniversityAddReviewTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.user = User.objects.create(
            username="username", 
            password="password", 
            email="email")

        ....
```

and then

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    review = Review(
        university=university,
        user=self.user,
        summary=request.POST['summary'])

review.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

I could make it work, with the following lines:

```py
import unittest # instead of (from django.test import TestCase)

class NameTest(unittest.TestCase):
    #lines to test your code here...
```